# Passing a variable into Left(string, VariableHere) not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data import file that has dates on it without a comma (i.e. `January 1 2015`). Excel won't recognize this as a date, and I need to work with these dates to find other dates (i.e. Date + Length of trip to find the last day of the trip, etc.)

I'm trying to use VBA to accomplish this and have the logic down but I'm encountering an error.

I'm taking the length of the date (`January 1 2015`), the 5 right characters (`2015`), the left of the whole length minus the 5 right characters(`JANUARY 1`), and then combining these variables with a comma inserted: `Left(value-5) & ", " & Right(value, 5)`

I'm using this code:

```
    'correct date from JANUARY 1 2000 to JANUARY 1, 2000 so excel can recognize as date

    LengthTrpDpt = Len(wb1.Sheets("BL Import").Cells(ioi, TrpDepCol)) 'length of date
    LengthRightTrpDPt = Right(wb1.Sheets("BL Import").Cells(ioi, TrpDepCol), 5) 'finds right 5 of date " 2015"
    NewListedDate = Left(wb1.Sheets("BL Import").Cells(ioi, TrpDepCol), LengthTrpDpt - 5) & ", " & LengthRightTrpDPt
```

The problem is with the NewListedDate variable. I can change the part LengthTrpDpt - 5 to a number and it works fine. For some reason I can't have an equation here though. I tried perform the equation in a separately saved variable (LengthMath = LengthTrpDpt - 5) and using LengthMath instead, but that doesn't work either.

LengthTrpDpt works fine and MsgBox's the correct number. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just `Split()` the date string to get your three parts, then piece them back together however you'd like:

```
Dim a
a = Split(wb1.Sheets("BL Import").Cells(ioi, TrpDepCol))
NewListedDate = a(0) & " " & a(1) & ", " & a(2)
```

Comment: Use t2c on the column od text-that-looks-like-dates.

Comment: This looked promising but I get errors after playing with it for a while. How does the split on the bottom work exactly? Is it separating by the spaces in the string? So a(0)=January, a(1)=22, a(2)=2015 ? Thanks!

Comment: Yep. By default, `Split()` separates based on the space character.

Comment: This seems like the way to go, but I'm getting an error with ' NewListedDate = a(0) & " " & a(1) & ", " & a(2) '

Comment: What's different about the date you're getting an error on? And what's the error?

Comment: I'm getting 'Runtime 9 Error; Subscript out of range'

Comment: That should only happen if your date string has < 2 spaces.

Comment: Ugh my heads totally blown. It's actually working and changing these values to dates. Not sure how it's getting an error.. I'll keep tinkering

Comment: ohh got it. At maximum I import 60 dates. ioi represents For ioi = 1 to 60; it's getting the error after it runs of out of dates to sort if there isn't 60 total.  Working on fix now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) on the column of text-that-look-like-dates.

```
with worksheets("Sheet1").columns(1)  '<-change this to reflect the actual worksheet and column
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.cells(1,1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth,  FieldInfo:=Array(0, 3)
end with
```

The **0** tells T2C that it should just put everything back into the original column. The **3** is the MDY [TextFileColumnDataTypes property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215749%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

imho, it is ALWAYS better to work with numbers and dates rather than a string representation approximating them.

Comment: I was able to run this without errors, but it didn't change any cells in the column where the dates are stored (January 1 2015 is still January 1 2015) and I can't work with them as date (for instance, "January 1 2015+2 = error)

Comment: Very odd indeed. I tested that on twenty cells in a column holding your example string data of `"January 1 201"` and it worked exactly as planned. I strongly suspect that you have leading/trailing spaces or non-breaking spaces and/or interspersed non-breaking spaces. The failure to use the [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx) frm the other response would seem to cnfirm this.

Comment: I tested this, too, and it worked for me. It's a good answer.